# Modelling reference to embedding document using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am modelling two types of events (events and subevents) in a MongoDB like this:

```
var EventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    'name' : String,
    'subEvent' : [ SubeventSchema ]
});

var SubeventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    'name' : String
});
```

Now when I query a subevent I want to be able to also retrieve data about its corresponding superevent, so that some example data retrieved using Mongoose population feature could look like this:

```
EventModel.findOne({
    name : 'Festival'
})
.populate('subEvent')
.execute(function (err, evt) { return evt; });

{
    name : 'Festival',
    subEvent: [
        { name : 'First Concert' },
        { name : 'Second Concert' }
    ]
}

EventModel.findOne({
    'subEvent.name' : 'FirstConcert'
}, {
    'subEvent.$' : 1
})
.populate('superEvent') // This will not work, this is the actual problem of my question
.execute(function (err, subevt) { return subevt; });

{
    name: 'First Concert',
    superEvent: {
        name: 'Festival'
    }
}
```

A solution I can think of is not to embed but to reference like this:

```
var EventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    'name' : String,
    'subEvent' : [ {
        'type' : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        'ref' : 'SubeventSchema'
    } ]
});

var SubeventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    'name' : String,
    'superEvent' : {
        'type' : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        'ref' : 'EventSchema'
    }
});
```

I am looking for a solution based on the first example using embedded subevents, though. Can this be achieved and in case yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

I think your mental model of document embedding isn't correct. The major misunderstanding (and this is very common) is that you "query a subevent" (query an embedded document). According to your current `Event` schema, a `Subevent` is just a document embedded in an `Event` document. The embedded `SubEvent` is not a top-level document; it's not a member of any collection in MongoDB. Therefore, you don't query for it. You query for `Event`s (which are the actual collection-level documents in your schema) whose `subEvents` have certain properties. E.g. one way people translate the query

```
db.events.find({ "subEvent" : { "name" : "First Concert" } })
```

into plain English is as "find all the subevents with the name "First Concert". This is wrong. The right translation is "find all events that have at least one subevent whose name is "First Concert" (the "at least one" part depends on knowledge that `subEvent` is an array).

Coming back to the specific question, you can hopefully see now that trying to do a populate of a "superevent" on a subevent makes no sense. Your queries return events. The optimal schema, be it subevents embedded in events, one- or two-way references between events and subevents documents in separate collections, or events denormalized into the constituent subevent documents, cannot be determined from the information in the question because the use case is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a situation where you need to modify your thinking rather than the schema itself. Mongoose [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) supports the basic ideas of MongoDB "projection", or more commonly referred to as "field selection". So rather than try to model around this, just select the fields you want to populate.

So your second schema form is perfectly valid, just change how you populate:

```
EventModel.find({}).populate("subEvent", "name").execute(function(err,docs) {

  // "subevent" array items only contain "name" now

});
```

This is actually covered in the Mongoose documentation under the ["populate"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) section.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have read the corresponding docs and your solution is in fact what I meant in my second example. This would force me to change the schema, which is currently following my first example. I will add some more detail to my question.

Comment: @hielsnoppe You can go away and change if you really wish. But your question is still basically "how do I limit the fields returned from the related schema under populate". This is basically what is answered, and nothing much is going to change that. So if you want more fields in your related schema then you are going to have to add them. No other way around that unless your schema is not "strict"

Comment: So you mean I will have to add a `superEvent` field to the `SubeventSchema` referencing the event that the subevent is embedded in? This seems redundant as the association should be clear through the embedding, but I will do this if there is no other way. Also can this not lead to a loop during population?

Comment: @hielsnoppe How on earth do you **think** you can possibly have a property that you can access without actually including it? And if you don't actually want to access it then **don't** include it at all. Honestly, this is not that hard to work out.